# Where is Teams Organization data stored?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Teams has a tab called Organization, that looks like this:
[image]
Where is this data stored/ how could I recreate this data in c#? Is this something that can be pulled with the teams api?

EDIT: Found the issue, It turns out the data was there, but graph only returns 100 results at a time : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56707771/11875152

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)? It looks like an [organization resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/organization?view=graph-rest-1.0) is available.

Comment: @tnw I dont understand. How could I get heirarchy data from that? If you send that req, here : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-1) it does not return anything about org data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API to get Organization Hierarchy of Azure AD is **NOT** exposed today. You can vote up the related [User Voice Post](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39254014-get-the-entire-manager-hierarchy).

Currently we can get one level managers or employees using Microsoft Graph API. (You can test it using [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer))

[List manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-get-manager):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/manager
```

[List directReports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-directreports?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/directReports
```

Comment: Any Idea where the teams data comes from? if I get all users with managers, it is not all users in the org. Somehow not all users have a manager in graph, but they do have a manager in teams.

Comment: @LukedukeAnimations I see from my side that they are consistent, maybe the data I tested is not sufficient. As far as I know, this data should be in AAD, and it is very likely that there is a set of synchronized data in Sharepoint. But as I have mentioned, there is not an API that can list the Organization Hierarchy.

Comment: By using Graph call you will receive the [direct reporters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-directreports?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request), and based on the result you need to handle custom logic to show on the repartees to respective manager on tab.

Comment: @LukedukeAnimations Do you have any other concerns? If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AllenWu Sure, But It doesnt work for me. Not sure why, but it does not have a manager for many users in graph, but does in teams.

Comment: @AllenWu See the edit, The data was there, it just only returns 100 results at a time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56707771/11875152